# Closing ResultSet in Java 7

Tags: java, jdbc

The following site shows using the new "AutoClosable" features with JDBC: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_41.html). This site is showing how the Statement will be automatically closed, but the result set is not in the try() section where it would be auto-closed. So, my question is, do I NOT need to close ResultSets directly in Java 7?  I have always used the pattern: close resultset, close statement, close connection.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [Javadoc of ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object
>   that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next
>   result from a sequence of multiple results.

Comment: thanks, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: BTW: ResultSets are also `AutoCloseable`, so there is nothing keeping you from using try-with-resources to close the resultset as soon as possible.