# Is Try-Catch More or Less Expensive Than Try-With-Resources

Tags: java, exception

## Question

I've just started getting back into Java recently and never had an opportunity to use `try-with-resources`. On the surface it looks great as it can cut down on code, but under the hood is it more or less expensive of an operation than the traditional `try-catch`? I know `try-catch` already is an expensive operation, hence my curiosity.

I gave both types a simple test and didn't notice much of a difference at all:

## Test Examples

### Try-With-Resources Test

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
ArrayList<String> list = null;

try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"))) {
    list = new ArrayList();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        list.add(sc.next());
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("The program completed in " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
}
```

### Traditional Try-Catch Test

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
ArrayList<String> list = null;
Scanner sc = null;

try {
    sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    list = new ArrayList();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        list.add(sc.next());
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
} finally {
    sc.close();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("The program completed in " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
}
```

### Results

Both resulted in a time of 15-16ms - no real noticeable difference at all. But admittedly this is a very small test example.

My question again: Under the hood is `try-with-resources` more or less expensive than a traditional `try-catch`?

Comment: Check the bytecode generated by using `javap -c YourClassCompiled.class`. If it's the same, then there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1

Comment: You can't measure millisecond-level delays with `currentTimeMillis`. The granularity is probably 15-16 ms, meaning it'll always report some multiple of that. Benchmarking is a complicated affair and the naive approach is seldom correct - see [Nanotrusting nanotime](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/).

Comment: The difference between the try-with-resources and your try-catch is that your try-catch is buggy. `sc.close()` may throw a `NullPointerException`. Even if the try-with-resources had a performance impact (which it doesn't), always use it. It will prevent bugs like these.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. try-catch is not the expensive part. *Throwing* the exception is (generating the stacktrace).
2. "Expensive" above means "costs some microseconds".
3. try-with-resources is just try-catch with proper code needed to reliably close the resource.
4. Your measurement code cannot prove anything due to all the well-known pitfalls of trying to measure performance within an optimizing runtime such as HotSpot. You need to warm up, repeat the same many times, and much more.
5. If your result is above 10 ms, then clearly you cannot have an issue with try-catch, which can altogether impose an overhead of several microseconds.

Comment: Interesting. It appears I have some reading to do. Thanks for the clear answer.

Comment: @Drew Take a look at [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) if you're interested in benchmarking Java code. I haven't used it yet, but it is designed for just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 11):

It's apples and oranges. An ARM (automatic resource management, or try-with-resources) block does more than the old-fashioned try-catch-finally block that you show. That's because it generates the code to handle exceptions that are thrown in resource closure with the [suppression mechanism.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getSuppressed--) (A [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321879/3474) discusses this in some detail.)

If you are writing new code, use an ARM block. It is easier to read, maintain, and it does more. Unless you are running in a tightly constrained environment (like a smart card), these advantages are likely to outweigh the cost of a few extra byte codes.

Answer (score 4):

Try-catch-finally and try-with-resources have essentially the same performance because under the covers they generate essentially the same bytecode.

However, your second version (try..catch..finally) is not quite formulated correctly as it could (in theory) lead to an undesirable `NullPointerException` when `sc.close()` is called. If the act of constructing a `Scanner` causes an exception to be thrown then `sc` will not be assigned and will be `null`.

You should construct the Scanner outside of the `try..finally` and change this:

```
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    ...
```

to:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
try {
    ...
```

Alternatively, you should check that `sc != null` in the `finally` clause before calling `sc.close()`. This won't be necessary if you create the scanner outside of the try..finally, so I would recommend you do that.

To do the same job as try-with-resources, you will also need to put a second `try..catch` around the `sc.close()` with an empty catch block, to ignore any exceptions thrown during close. If you do that, I suppose you don't need to worry so much about the null check.

Comment: Excellent point! Sloppily initializing to null like that is a bad habit too many programmers indulge in.

Comment: @erickson agreed. was more focused on the example than practices.

Comment: Yep, I was just being pedantic :-)

Answer (score 0):

Traditional Try-catch: In the try block, your code may have a exception, and this exception will be throw and then catch by the catch-block. Then the catch block will deal with the exception. And if you open a source, like a file or other things before a `try`, and you need to close them in `finally` then the `close()` executes in the `finally` may also throw a exception, and this will replace the exception which are throw in `try` This sitiution is solved by a nested try-catch before SE 7 like this

```java
try
{
   try
  {
      code with exception;
  }
   finally
 {
      close();
 }

}
catch(Exception e)
{
  Deal the exception
}
```

this is really complex, so After SE 7 we use try-with-resource to solve this problem when you finish the `try` block, the resource in `try(Here)` will all be closed.

reference "Core Java" Edition:9 based on SE 7