# select count(*) returns true regardless of the existing account

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The AccountCheck method is returning false always and saying "Account exists!" always. Idea is to check if there's an existing account in the database and create one if it doesn't. Please help. I am not doing any validations in the code.

```
private boolean AccountCheck(String username, String password) {

    try {

        String sql = "select count(*) from user where username=? and password=?";

        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, username);
        pst.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {

            rs.close();
            System.out.println("Account exists!");
            return false;

        } else {

            rs.close();
            System.out.println("Accout does not exist!");
            return true;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if record doesnt exist count will return "0" as output. So `rs.next()` will return true always.

Solution :

Replace `select count(*) from user where username=? and password=?` with

`select * from user where username=? and password=?`

If you use `*` instead of `count(*)` it will not return any record

Comment: Thanks, trying it now!

Answer (score 1):

As you are querying for `count`, it will always return one record (with value 0 if no account exists), in this case, it will always go inside `if`. We can make wither of the below changes to make it work:

1. Change count(*) to *, e.g.: `select * from user where username=? and password=?`
2. Get the count from resultset and check the value:

   `String sql = "select count(*) as count from user where username=? and password=?";`
   `PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   pst.setString(1, username);
   pst.setString(2, password);
   ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
   if (rs.next() && rs.getInt("count") > 0) {
       rs.close();
       System.out.println("Account exists!");
       return false;
   } else {
       rs.close();
       System.out.println("Accout does not exist!");
       return true;
   }`

Also, you may want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321418/where-to-close-java-preparedstatements-and-resultsets) SO answer regarding how to close `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` objects.